# SQL - specifying a condition in COUNT / returning a value from the same field more than once in one SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT u.USER_NAME AS [User]
    ,COUNT(ad.ACTIVITY_ID) AS [Total Activities Late]
FROM USERS u
INNER JOIN ACTIVITY_DATA ad ON u.USER_ID = ad.USER_ID
WHERE ad.DAYS_LATE > 0
    AND ad.COMPLETED_DATE IS NULL
GROUP BY u.USER_NAME

SELECT u.USER_NAME AS [User]
    ,COUNT(ad.ACTIVITY_ID) AS [Upto One Week Late]
FROM USERS u
INNER JOIN ACTIVITY_DATA ad ON u.USER_ID = ad.USER_ID
WHERE ad.DAYS_LATE BETWEEN 1 AND 7
    AND ad.COMPLETED_DATE IS NULL
GROUP BY u.USER_NAME
```

Both of these selects work fine, however I would like to return the total number of activities late and the total number of activities upto one week late inside the same SELECT statement. Is this possible?

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, you just need to use a SUM and a CASE statement.  Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT u.USER_NAME As [User]
  , COUNT(ad.ACTIVITY_ID) As [Total Activities Late]
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ad.DAYS_LATE BETWEEN 1 and 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As [Upto One Week Late]
  FROM USERS u
  JOIN ACTIVITY_DATA ad
    ON u.USER_ID = ad.USER_ID
  WHERE ad.DAYS_LATE > 0 AND ad.COMPLETED_DATE is NULL
  GROUP BY u.USER_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this instead using `SUM()` function and specifying the condition using a `CASE` statement

```
  SELECT u.USER_NAME As [User], 
  SUM(CASE WHEN ad.DAYS_LATE > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As [Total Activities Late],
  SUM(CASE WHEN ad.DAYS_LATE BETWEEN 1 and 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As [Upto One Week Late]
  FROM USERS u
  JOIN ACTIVITY_DATA ad ON u.USER_ID = ad.USER_ID
  WHERE ad.COMPLETED_DATE is NULL
  GROUP BY u.USER_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-- CASE is your friend. CASE inside an aggregate is best-friend
-- Remember: aggregates ignore nulls
SELECT u.USER_NAME As [User],    
COUNT(CASE ad.DAYS_LATE BETWEEN 1 and 7 AND ad.COMPLETED_DATE is NULL THEN ad.ACTIVITY_ID END) As  [Upto One Week Late]
COUNT(CASE WHEN ad.DAYS_LATE > 0 AND ad.COMPLETED_DATE THEN ad.ACTIVITY_ID END) As [Total Activities Late],
FROM USERS u    
JOIN ACTIVITY_DATA ad
ON u.USER_ID = ad.USER_ID
GROUP BY u.USER_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.USER_NAME As [User], (SELECT COUNT(ad.ACTIVITY_ID)
                               FROM USERS ua
                               JOIN ACTIVITY_DATA ad ON ua.USER_ID = ad.USER_ID
                               WHERE ad.DAYS_LATE > 0 
                               AND ad.COMPLETED_DATE is NULL
                               AND ua.USER_ID = u.USER_ID
                               GROUP BY ua.USER_NAME) As [Total Activities Late],
                              (SELECT COUNT(ad.ACTIVITY_ID) 
                               FROM USERS ub
                               JOIN ACTIVITY_DATA ad ON ub.USER_ID = ad.USER_ID
                               WHERE ad.DAYS_LATE BETWEEN 1 
                               AND 7 AND ad.COMPLETED_DATE is NULL 
                               AND ub.USER_ID = u.USER_ID
                               GROUP BY ub.USER_NAME) As [Upto One Week Late]
FROM USERS u
GROUP BY u.USER_NAME
```